# Elastic Beanstalk silently fails for long processes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I have a Plotly Dash application in a Docker container deployed with Elastic Beanstalk. Everything looks and runs fine, except when I run a process that takes a long time to complete. The longer processes will run, but then when a graph should be populated it does not return any graph at all. I can see in the logs that the operation is running, but the graph is not populated unless the process is shorter (< 45s approx).

I am using Amazon Linux 2 Docker + classic load balancer + nginx.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV DASH_DEBUG_MODE False
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN set -ex && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8050
CMD gunicorn -w 4 --timeout 500 -b 0.0.0.0:8050 application:server
```

I've tried with `CMD ["python", "application.py"]` as well.

I've tried using .ebextensions and .platform to modify options.config and nginx.conf but neither have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk also uses gunicorn which overrides the gunicorn in the Dockerfile.

You have to add a Procfile in the root of your app directory.

```
web: gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --threads 2 --timeout 500 project.wsgi:application
```